# react-native-vector-icons: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2]

Tags: react-native, sonarqube, gradlew

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
> [androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0] C:\Users\basudeb.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\66a9e1a6e4b8eebc04324103ea2d975f\vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
> Package name 'androidx.vectordrawable' used in: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.

> Task :react-native-webview:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
> [androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0] C:\Users\basudeb.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\66a9e1a6e4b8eebc04324103ea2d975f\vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
> Package name 'androidx.vectordrawable' used in: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.
> C:\Projects\PPMS\dppms-mobile-app\dppmsapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\manifestMerger4131386382709277537.xml:5:5-74 Error:
> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2] C:\Users\basudeb.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bb3fca3d3b3f84f0b6ffab25815bd65b\jetified-react-native-0.64.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
520 actionable tasks: 512 executed, 8 up-to-date

Comment: Your answer is in the **error**. Go to the `android` folder in your react-native project. Open project level `build.gradle`, search for `minSdkVersion` and upgrade its value to 21. That's all.

Comment: Tried to change the minsdk version to 21 but still the same issue

Comment: Delete your `node_modules` and `yarn.lock or package-json.lock`, run `npm/yarn install`. After that, `cd android`. If you're using windows run `gradlew clean` if using Mac or Linux run `./gradlew clean`, and try to run the application.

Comment: Don't delete your .lock files, that will trash the versions of dependencies you have pinned.